# Identity of inverse matrix

Tags: matrices

How can I prove that

$$(C_{N}^{-1} + W_{N})^{-1} = C_{N}(I + W_{N}C_{N})^{-1}$$

I tried to use the Woodbury identity:

$$(A + BD^{-1}C)^{-1} = A^{-1}-A^{-1}B(D+CA^{-1}B)^{-1}CA^{-1}$$

which seems to be useful in this case, but I can't simplify enough to get the result.

Suggestions?

Comment: What happens when you just multiply the RHS by $C_N^{-1} + W_N$?

Comment: Oh, I get it. So simple. Put your comment as an answer, so I can select it as a correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens when you just multiply the RHS by $C_N^{-1} + W_N$?

Answer (score 2):

Think about what happens if they were just numbers (but don't forget that it's not commutative):

Let's call $A:=C_N$ and $B:=W_N$ for simplicity. If these were numbers, you are looking for $\displaystyle\frac1{1/A\,+B}$. Now we want to pull out $\displaystyle\frac1{1/A}$ (alias $A$) from the left, so that, because of the inverse, we have to pull out $1/A$ from the right:
$$1/A+B=(1+BA)\cdot 1/A\\
\frac1{1/A\,+B}=\frac1{1/A}\cdot\frac1{1+BA}\,.$$
Writing it with inverses, we get the same line:

> As $A^{-1}+B=(I+BA)A^{-1}$, we have
>   $$(A^{-1}+B)^{-1}= A(I+BA)^{-1}\,.$$

Comment: That's ingenious. How far can I push that analogy? (assuming I take care of the commutative property)

Comment: Multiplication is multiplication.

Comment: Well, the directions are not that trivial. When I first wrote up, it wanted to be $1+AB$, but since the inverse changes the direction, actually $A^{-1}$ was pulled out from the right, so it became $1+BA$.

Comment: Right. That's why I asked. I can imagine that as long as an identity is obtained only by left or right multiplications, then I can apply it as a matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Another simpler trick :
$$(C_{N}^{-1}+W_{N}^{})^{-1}_{}=[(I+W_{N}^{}C_{N}^{})C_{N}^{-1}]^{-1}_{}=(C_{N}^{-1})^{-1}_{}(I+W_{N}^{}C_{N}^{})^{-1}_{}=C_{N}^{}(I+W_{N}^{}C_{N}^{})^{-1}_{}$$